# How to implement string pattern matching using a variety of inputs/modes in Rust

Tags: rust, idioms

I ran into a problem with Rust's Pattern trait in relation to the str.find() method, in that if I tried to write a more flexible and complex function that USES str.find() I cant actually take a Pattern in my arguments list:

```rust
use std::str::pattern::Pattern;

fn find_complex(string: &str, pattern: Pattern) -> Option<usize> {
    // do something complex before using the native find
    return string.find(pattern)
}
```

results in compiler diagnostic:

```
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'pattern': API not fully fleshed out and ready to be stabilized
 --> src/find_zero.rs:3:40
  |
3 | fn find_complex(string: &str, pattern: Pattern) -> Option<usize> {
  |                                        ^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: see issue #27721 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27721> for more information
```

So I decided rather than dealing with Rust's silly reasons for keeping something so simple in the unstable branch, I decided to just make my own.

In doing so, I came to a conundrum: what is the right way to implement it such that most other users would look at it and say, "Yup that looks just like how it should be implemented."

I came up with 2 different ideas, but each seem to have problems/limitations in their design...

##### As a trait that each possible pattern type implements

```rust
pub struct StringMatch<'a> {
    index: usize,
    length: usize,
    value: &'a str
}

pub struct StringQulaifierMatch {
    index: usize,
    length: usize,
}

pub trait StringPattern {
    fn find_in<'a>(self, string: &'a str) -> Option<StringMatch<'a>>;
}

impl StringPattern for char {
    fn find_in<'a>(self, string: &'a str) -> Option<StringMatch<'a>> {
        todo!() // Find single char match and return index, byte length, and string slice of match location
    }
}

impl StringPattern for &str {
    fn find_in<'a>(self, string: &'a str) -> Option<StringMatch<'a>> {
        todo!() // Find string match and return index, byte length, and string slice of match location
    }
}

impl StringPattern for Vec<char> {
    fn find_in<'a>(self, string: &'a str) -> Option<StringMatch<'a>> {
        todo!() // Find any char match and return index, byte length, and string slice of match location
    }
}

impl StringPattern for Vec<&str> {
    fn find_in<'a>(self, string: &'a str) -> Option<StringMatch<'a>> {
        todo!() // Find any string match and return index, byte length, and string slice of match location
    }
}

impl<F> StringPattern for F 
where F : Fn(&str) -> Option<StringQulaifierMatch> {
    fn find_in<'a>(self, string: &'a str) -> Option<StringMatch<'a>> {
        todo!() // Find match by iteratively increasing char index and passing &string[index..] to closure looking for Some(StringQulaifierMatch)
    }
}
```

This looked good for a while until I got to the bottom and realized I couldnt do a blanket implementation for different closures with different signatures for... *some reason*.

In addition, it seems awkward to be calling the find function on the pattern and passing it the full string instead of the other way around.

##### Each pattern type is an enum variant

```rust
pub struct StringMatch<'a> {
    index: usize,
    length: usize,
    value: &'a str
}

pub struct StringQulaifierMatch {
    index: usize,
    length: usize,
}

pub enum StringPattern<'a> {
    Char(char),
    String(&'a str),
    CharList(Vec<char>),
    StringList(Vec<&'a str>),
    Qualifier(Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> Option<StringQulaifierMatch>>)
}

pub trait PatternMatching {
    fn match_pattern<'a>(&'a self, pattern: StringPattern) -> StringMatch<'a>;
}

impl PatternMatching for str {
    fn match_pattern<'a>(&'a self, pattern: StringPattern) -> StringMatch<'a> {
        match pattern {
            StringPattern::Char(char_pattern) => todo!(), // Find single char match and return index, byte length, and string slice of match location// Find single char match and return index, byte length, and string slice of match location
            StringPattern::String(string_pattern) => todo!(), // Find string match and return index, byte length, and string slice of match location
            StringPattern::CharList(char_list) => todo!(), // Find any char match and return index, byte length, and string slice of match location
            StringPattern::StringList(string_list) => todo!(), // Find any string match and return index, byte length, and string slice of match location
            StringPattern::Qualifier(qualifier) => todo!(), // Find match by iteratively increasing char index and passing &string[index..] to closure looking for Some(StringQulaifierMatch)
        }
    }
}
```

This looks nice at first because enums are so idiomatic, but in order to implement the behavoir for every possible version, you have to branch off with some sort of match block or equivalent. This doesn't get the benefit of generics where only the concrete versions you end up useing get monomorphized and compiled and the unused ones stay in source.

Which way would be OVERALL the best/most-idiomatic/most-flexible/least-error-prone way to do things? Other solutions welcome as well!

Comment: _"Rust's silly reasons for keeping something so simple in the unstable branch"_ -- It's not silly to fully bake something before releasing it. Anything released in a programming language realistically needs to be supported _forever_ and cannot be changed in backwards-incompatible ways. Making damn sure you get something right the first time is a good thing.

Comment: This also seems kind of opinion based, or perhaps more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  My initial impression is that the trait approach is the way to go, because then your downstream users can implement their own patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have actually solved my own problem:

This way seems to be the "correct" way to do what I want, sorry for troubling y'all!

```rust
pub trait PatternMatching<T> {
    fn find_pattern<'a>(&'a self, pattern: T) -> StringMatch<'a>;
}

impl PatternMatching<char> for str {
    fn find_pattern<'a>(&'a self, pattern: char) -> StringMatch<'a> {
        todo!() 
    }
}

impl PatternMatching<&str> for str {
    fn find_pattern<'a>(&'a self, pattern: &str) -> StringMatch<'a> {
        todo!() 
    }
}

impl PatternMatching<Vec<char>> for str {
    fn find_pattern<'a>(&'a self, pattern: Vec<char>) -> StringMatch<'a> {
        todo!() 
    }
}

impl PatternMatching<Vec<&str>> for str {
    fn find_pattern<'a>(&'a self, pattern: Vec<&str>) -> StringMatch<'a> {
        todo!() 
    }
}

impl PatternMatching<Box<dyn Fn(&str) -> StringQulaifierMatch>> for str {
    fn find_pattern<'a>(&'a self, pattern: Box<dyn Fn(&'a str) -> StringQulaifierMatch>) -> StringMatch<'a> {
        todo!() 
    }
}

impl PatternMatching<Box<dyn Fn(char) -> bool>> for str {
    fn find_pattern<'a>(&'a self, pattern: Box<dyn Fn(char) -> bool>) -> StringMatch<'a> {
        todo!() 
    }
}
```

You get to use traits for downstream flexibility, and can also accept multiple types of closures.